# React Native: scrollTo() in ScrollView after Redux Storage has loaded

Tags: android, react-native, redux, scrollview

**Update:** The problem occurs on Android 6.0.

In [my React Native app](https://github.com/georgjaehnig/qr-show/), I have a [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) showing QR codes, one at the
time. The ScrollView uses `pagingEnabled={true}`, so it always displays
exactly one QR code centered.

I am also using [Redux storage](https://github.com/react-stack/redux-storage) to remember

- the index of the current QR code displayed
- the QR codes themselves (e.g. the value that they encode)

In case no codes are in the storage, 2 default initial codes are set in the reducer.

### The Goal:

When I start the app, I want the same code displayed as last time when the app was closed. This means that the scroll offset should be set to this code.

### The Problem:

After startup, the app will only scroll to the first or second code but never to any higher. So for instance, if my last displayed QR code had `index=3`, I will still only see the second QR code.

### My analysis / assumption what goes wrong

When my app starts, there are at first (for some milliseconds) no codes
available from the storage, so the app renders with the 2 default initial
ones. Apparently during this time, the scrolling is attempted, so it stops at the first code, and this index is remembered.

However:

My `scrollToCurrentCode()` function is called at `componentDidUpdate`. At
this point, the codes **are** already loaded from the storage, as I could see
via `console.log()`.

However 2:

`load(store).then((newState) => { console.log('loaded'); })` will log at
last, even after `componentDidUpdate`. So maybe the whole loading process
takes a while? If so, how can I postpone the triggering of
`componentDidUpdate` after the loading actually happened.

Below is a whole excerpt from the console, with some comments from me:

```
  render                // First render with initial data.
  componentDidMount
  render                // Second render with data from storage.
  componentDidUpdate    // Now I want to scroll to the code.
  codes.length 5        // These are the proper codes from the storage.
  currentCodeIndex 3    // Also the correct index is thre.
  loaded                // This comes from load(store).then()
  render                // Another render starts, triggered from scrollToCurrentCode()
  componentDidUpdate
  codes.length 5
  currentCodeIndex 1
```

I know this might be a very complex problem, I tried my best to explain it.
Here is also the [full source code of the project](https://github.com/georgjaehnig/qr-show/).

Comment: what happens if you call `scrollToCurrentCode()` in `componentDidMount` of your `MainScreen`?

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing. Still the problem was there: It did scroll only to the second code, as if no more were available. https://github.com/georgjaehnig/qr-show/blob/master/js/MainScreen.js#L276

Comment: I now found a hacky "solution" using setTimeout... :(

Comment: Seems my problem is basically: How to set the initial offset of a ScrollView? And this does not read as if there's a correct solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6849

Comment: the delay indeed sounds hacky.. maybe something's causing delays with the render. you can try to wrap it with `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions`.

Comment: I don't think it's related to initial offset. If there's no content, you can't scroll there anyway

Comment: also, in your comment you pointed out to your code in `componentDidUpdate`, I suggested that you call the scrolling method in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Oh, sorry for misreading this. OK, now I tried to call it in `componentDidMount()`. But I get the error that the property `scrollTo()` is not available. As expected, since componentDidMount is called way earlier than `componentDidUpdate`, even before `render()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141823/discussion-between-artal-and-georg-jahnig).